# Remove Corona SDK element / function

Tags: lua, sdk, coronasdk

has form.lua file with code

```
local _M = {}

function _M.calc( a )

    local quad = display.newRect(100,100,100,100)
end
return _M
```

and the file scene2.lua with the code

```
local form = require "form"

form.calc( )
```

I need the "quad / function" to be removed from the screen when it goes to another scene.

Comment: yea, now do a translate to English.

Answer (score 0):

Add display object to scene group so composer remove it for you.

form.lua

```
local _M = {}

function _M.calc( group )

    local quad = display.newRect( group, 100,100,100,100)
end
return _M
```

scene2.lua

```
local form = require "form"

form.calc( scene.view )
```